# What's the fastest way to find the most commonly used char in a string

Tags: python

I have written a couple of functions that accept a string and return the most common used char in it. I'm interest to know what's most efficient way to achieve this and the reasons behind it.

For the purpose of this test I'm using `Python 3.7.3` on a Mac.

Here's what I have:

```py
from collections import Counter


def max_char(str):
    return Counter(str).most_common(1)[0][0]


def max_char3(str):
    return max(str, key=str.count)


def max_char2(str):
    counter = 0
    max_char = None
    max_char_nr = 0

    while len(str):
        char = str[0]
        char_count = str.count(char)
        str = str.replace(char, '')

        if char_count > max_char_nr:
            max_char_nr = char_count
            max_char = char

        counter += 1

    return max_char


def max_char1(str):
    chars = {}

    for s in str:
        if s in chars:
            chars[s] += 1
        else:
            chars[s] = 1

    output = ''
    max_num = 0
    for c in chars:
        if chars[c] > max_num:
            output = c
            max_num = chars[c]

    return output
```

I've tested them using `timeit` with `1000000` iterations where `str='abcdefghijklmnaaaaa'` and the results are:

```
max_char took: 5.538845853000001
max_char1 took: 2.283595664
max_char2 took: 5.975449033
max_char3 took: 2.9375215150000002
```

Why is `max_char1` which has (as far as I understand) a `O(n+n)` complexity the fastest. Shouldn't using python built-in functions like in `max_char` or `max_char3` be more efficient?

Thanks

EDIT1: added test data method's argument

---

**UPDATE 1**

As some of you suggested the reasoning for this has to do with the data size we pass in the routines.

When tested with
`str='Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.'`

we get

```
max_char took: 11.161055726999999
max_char1 took: 13.953004615000001
max_char2 took: 14.024967180999997
max_char3 took: 37.395588314
```

So a this point we can assume that the fastest way to solve this problem is to use a `Counter` container.

Comment: I’m very surprised that `max_char` isn’t the fastest. `max_char2` and `max_char3` are inefficient time-complexity-wise. What size of string are you trying?

Comment: you didnt include your test string

Comment: I'm getting `max_char` a tad faster than `max_char1` using a string of 1000 random printable characters.

Comment: My bad :( I've updated the original post with the data I'm using for the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indicated you used `timeit`, but did not provide the test data initially. The size of the test data strongly affects the times you're measuring. If the test data is too small, you're just measuring the relative overhead.

Also, although you're right that standard python routines are generally very much optimised, they're are not necessarily optimised for the specific task you'd like to use them for, while you can write your own routines that are. In the case of `return max(str, key=str.count)` for example, it's very well possible that `str.count` is executed for every single character again and again, effectively counting them as often as they occur. Whereas your implementation only iterates over the characters once. Taking it from O(n+n) for `max_char1` to O(n^2) for `max` combined with `str.count`.

That `max_char` was slower, was surprising, since it pretty much does what you need it to exactly. When tested on longer strings, it's quicker than your code.

A few other notes:

- Using `str` as a variable name is a very bad idea, as it shadows the base Python `str` type.
- Depending on the characters you expect in the string, you may have faster options. For example, if your string is UTF and could contain any valid UTF character, the given solutions are probably close to optimal. However, if your string can only contain characters in a very limited range like `[a-z]` or something of the sort, you might be better off initialising a data structure that allows you to more quickly count specifically those characters, than relying on a `Counter` or `dict`.

Just running a simple test seems to indicate that anything quicker than the built-in Python routines is likely going to have to be C though. For example:

```py
def my_simple(s):
    result = [0] * 256
    for c in s:
        result[ord(c)] += 1
    return chr(result.index(max(result)))
```

Is still about twice as slow as `Counter(s).most_common(1)[0]`.

Comment: thanks Grismar. I've updated the original question with the data I'm using for testing. I'm going to try to run it with a bigger data set.

Comment: This is correct. When running the same routines with a larger dataset like `str='Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.'` the results are different. `max_char` is now the fastest with `11.161055726999999` followed by `max_char1` with `13.953004615000001`

Comment: Given how small the run-time of that operation is on that string (under 0.0003 seconds on average on my slow-ish laptop), the impact of overhead is still going to be fairly great, but of course you want to stay close to realistic performance. It's quite possible that the best solution for your problem is to go with a custom solution due to the low overhead, if your production data needs to be processed often and is almost always tiny.